# Uniqueness of map by dot product

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices

I know that for a map on a complex vector space we have that if $\langle Ax,x \rangle  = 0$
then $A = 0$ via the standard polarization trick. But what is the case if we are talking about real vector spaces? Is this then also true?

Comment: In the real case, polarisation gives $-A = A^t$, this is in Euclidian spaces equivalent to $\langle Ax,x\rangle = 0$ for all $x$.

Comment: @martini thanks, but how exactly do I see this? By polarization I meant: $ \langle A(x+\lambda y),x+ \lambda y \rangle = 0 $(where you use the values $1$ and $i$ for lambda in the complex case). The transpose may show up, if we look at the adjoint map $A^*=A^T$. So we get $ \langle (A - A^T)(x+y),x+y \rangle = 0 $ and then?

Comment: $\def\sp#1{\left\langle#1\right\rangle}$We have $$0=\sp{A(x+y),x+y} = \sp{Ax,y}+\sp{Ay,x} = \sp{(A+A^t)x, y}$$ for all $x,y$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, consider the rotation by $90^\circ$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$.